# Como ler a saída de um processo que funciona em loop? [C#]

Tags: c#, .net, processo

Tudo ocorre corretamente para iniciar o processo, mas ao tentar obter algum tipo de retorno de sua execução através de qualquer um dos  redirecionadores disponíveis, seja ele de entrada, saída ou erro, a aplicação trava. E isso porque, suponho, ele acessa uma aplicação que está funcionando em looping (trata-se de um sistema de socket), então ao tentar acessa-la ele *'trava'* dentro dela.

Eu imagino que a solução deva ser algo como iniciar esse processo através de um método e monitorar seu retorno através de outro, entretanto, eu não sei como fazer isso.

Como conseguir um resultado válido para `MessageBox.Show(processo.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd())` sem travar toda minha aplicação?

**Método utilizado:**

```
private void OpenCliente()
{                                    
    Process processo = new Process();
    bool output;

    processo.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = (Application.StartupPath + @"\Debug");                            
    processo.StartInfo.FileName = @"app.exe";                        
    processo.StartInfo.Arguments = "args";
    processo.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    processo.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
    processo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    processo.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    processo.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processo.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;            
    processo.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;
    processo.Start();

    MessageBox.Show(processo.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()); // Neste ponto o código trava
    processo.WaitForExit();
}
```

Comment: Caio, tem alguma mensagem de erro? posta aqui.

Comment: @AdjairCosta nenhuma mensagem de erro. A aplicação simplesmente para após executar o StandardOutput.ReadToEnd().

Comment: já tentou fazer uma aplicação console simples e usar esse código ? aparentemente, deve funcionar ok. já essa aplicação app.exe não tem como saber... é sua ? há alguma documentação ?

Comment: Não acredito que aplicar esse conceito em Consoles fará alguma diferença @RovannLinhalis, entretanto, farei o teste. Agradeço o conselho. Eu ocultei o nome da aplicação para que a pergunta pudesse ser a mais genérica possível. Foi proposital. Qualquer aplicação externa com a característica de estar em looping deve servir.

Comment: sim, minha intenção é saber se esse "app.exe" você que fez ou não...

Comment: Não. Esse app.exe não é de minha autoria. Trata-se de um sistema de socket, que independente de conseguir conectar-se ou não, entra em looping assim que é chamado. Isto considerando que o comando para conexão é passado nesse mesmo instante. O que eu gostaria era de conseguir ler o retorno que o aplicativo produz. Quando o executo via prompt eu sou capaz de lê-lo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ao invés de usar o objeto `StreamReader` retornado pela propriedade `Process.StandardOutput` ([documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput)), para capturar de forma síncrona o output do processo que você disparou, você poderia usar o evento `Process.OutputDataReceived` ([documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived)) para capturar de forma assíncrona o output do processo disparado.

Para fazer isso você precisa passar um *event handler*, com a assinatura do `DataReceivedEventHandler Delegate` ([documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.datareceivedeventhandler)) para o evento `Process.OutputDataReceived`.

Como você está usando `MessageBox.Show()`, eu imagino que esteja usando Windows Forms, e nesse caso eu sugiro que você exiba o output do processo disparado em um `TextBox`, ao invés de exibi-lo com `MessageBox`. Para isso é importante passar a referência do seu `Form` para a propriedade `Process.SynchronizingObject` ([documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.synchronizingobject)), caso contrário o seu *event handler* será executado em uma thread diferente da sua thread de GUI, e daria erro se você tentasse acessar o seu `TextBox` de dentro do *event handler*.

O código ficaria assim:

```
private void OpenCliente()
{
    Process processo = new Process();

    processo.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath + @"\Debug";    
    processo.StartInfo.FileName = @"app.exe";
    processo.StartInfo.Arguments = "args";
    processo.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    processo.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
    processo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    processo.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processo.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;

    //processo.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    processo.SynchronizingObject = this;

    processo.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => {
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
       {
          txtConsole.Text += e.Data + Environment.NewLine;
       }
    };

    processo.Start();
    // Dá início ao processo de leitura do output, e a partir
    // daqui o event handler será disparado a cada linha do output.
    processo.BeginOutputReadLine();
    processo.WaitForExit();
}
```

Mas eu pesquisei também esse problema de travamento que você relatou, e achei uma resposta no SO<sup>EN</sup> em que o autor disse que isso provavelmente ocorre porque o output é muito grande e excede a capacidade do buffer interno:

> [ProcessStartInfo hanging on “WaitForExit”? Why? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7608823/8133067)

---

**EDIÇÃO 1**

Pesquisei um pouco mais o assunto, e, olhando o código-fonte da classe `Process` ([Reference Source, função StartWithCreateProcess](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,2159)) pude ver que o objeto `StreamReader` criado para a propriedade `Process.StandardOutput` tem um *buffer* interno com tamanho igual 4096, ou seja, 4 KB:

```
if (startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput) {
   Encoding enc = (startInfo.StandardOutputEncoding != null) ? startInfo.StandardOutputEncoding : Console.OutputEncoding;
   standardOutput = new StreamReader(new FileStream(standardOutputReadPipeHandle, FileAccess.Read, 4096, false), enc, true, 4096);
}
```

Então, quando o resultado que seria exibido em tela pela aplicação disparada pela sua aplicação ultrapassa 4 KB, o buffer interno de output fica cheio, e aparentemente é isso que está causando o travamento da sua aplicação.

---

**EDIÇÃO 2**

Como um teste, você poderia abrir um Prompt de Comando (cmd.exe) e executar pela linha de comando essa aplicação que você dispara do seu programa, com os mesmos argumentos, redirecionando a saída para um arquivo texto:

```
C:\PastaSuaApp\Debug>app.exe args > app_saida.txt
```

Dessa forma você poderia verificar qual o tamanho do arquivo texto criado, e poderia checar se essa teoria dos 4 KB é verdadeira. Faça também um teste com argumentos que você sabe que não travam o seu programa, para ver se a saída ficou abaixo dos 4 KB.

---

**EDIÇÃO 3**

Esqueci de comentar que, se não for possível colocar um `TextBox` para exibir o resultado do output da aplicação alvo em *real-time*, é possível também jogar o resultado do output para um `StringBuilder`, como no exemplo da documentação do evento `Process.OutputDataReceived`, e mostrar esse resultado no final, da forma como você estava fazendo:

```
using System.Text;
//[...]

private StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

private void OpenCliente()
{
    Process processo = new Process();

    processo.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Application.StartupPath + @"\Debug";    
    processo.StartInfo.FileName = @"app.exe";
    processo.StartInfo.Arguments = "args";
    processo.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
    processo.StartInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
    processo.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    processo.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

    processo.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processo.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = true;

    processo.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => {
       if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Data))
       {
          output.Append(e.Data + Environment.NewLine);
       }
    };

    processo.Start();
    // Dá início ao processo de leitura do output, e a partir
    // daqui o event handler será disparado a cada linha do output.
    processo.BeginOutputReadLine();
    processo.WaitForExit();

    MessageBox.Show(output.ToString());
}
```

---

**EDIÇÃO 4**

O autor informou que ao executar o programa de terceiros usando a solução que eu sugeri, de redirecionamento assíncrono do output, nada era exibido, mas que quando o programa era executado diretamente no console, o output era exibido normalmente, mas também que ao fazer um redirecionamento no console usando `app.exe args > app_saida.txt`, nada era gravado no arquivo texto.

Eu achei [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7990851/8133067) no SOen em que o autor teve um problema muito parecido com este em questão, e um usuário [sugeriu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7990851/#comment9813069_7990851) que poderia simplesmente ser um bug no programa e perguntou se o autor contatou o fornecedor do programa. O autor depois [confirmou](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7990851/#comment26961093_8621612) que se tratava de um bug no programa, admitido pelo fornecedor, depois do contato. Então, se houver possibilidade de contactar o fornecedor, talvez seja uma saída.

Mas, outra forma que pensei para resolver o problema seria simplesmente iniciar o processo usando o *shell* do próprio sistema operacional, através da propriedade [`ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute) e deixando criar uma janela para o processo, com a propriedade [`ProcessStartInfo.CreateNoWindow`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.createnowindow).

Um exemplo de código:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "ping.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "pt.stackoverflow.com";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Se quiser que a tela fique sendo exibida por um tempo após o término do processo, pode acrescentar o tempo em milissegundos como um argumento no método `WaitForExit()`.

Mas se precisar que a tela de console fique aberta até o usuário fecha-la, pode-se executar o comando `cmd.exe /k <linha-de-comando>`, o único problema é que no final do processo o console estará disponível para o usuário interagir:

```
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "/k ping.exe pt.stackoverflow.com";
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: eu agradeço a resposta muito bem elaborada! É realmente um conhecimento de grande utilidade este a que você se determinou compartilhar, entretanto eu lamento ainda não ter sido o suficiente.

Comment: Não funcionou? Por que você diz que não foi o suficiente? Dê mais detalhes para tentarmos ajuda-lo.

Comment: O aplicativo trava no momento em que tento acessar a aplicação para obter a saída. Testando com o código que forneci, eu posso validar a tese de que ele fica preso dentro dessa aplicação externa pelo fato de que ao somente ao finaliza-la (a aplicação, não o aplicativo) pelo gerenciador de tarefas, o messageBox é então visto e o aplicativo volta ao normal.

Comment: Então, mas isso provavelmente é explicado por aquele link que te mandei, aparentemente o buffer interno do output da aplicação que você disparou ficou cheio. Você tentou a solução que eu passei?

Comment: Veja esse outro link: [What are the default values for StreamReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38584634/8133067). Aí diz que o tamanho padrão do buffer do objeto `StreamReader` é de 1024 bytes. Provavelmente o output da aplicação que você disparou é maior do que isso, e por isso o seu aplicativo trava. Da forma como eu sugeri, você não enche o buffer, porque recebe linha a linha o output.

Comment: Sim, você está correto! Por algum motivo que não compreendo precisei dar o `start` mais de uma vez para que conseguisse iniciar a aplicação. E apesar de alguma instabilidade, em alguns testes consegui ver o MessageBox (provavelmente somente algumas vezes pelo motivo que você tanto mencionou, o estouro do buffer interno). Além disso o MessageBox também veio vazio, mas acho que isso são outros quinhentos. Você foi de grande ajuda! Obrigado. Tomarei mais algum tempo para avaliar tudo, mas ao que me parece a sua resposta é correta para a pergunta. Se não, ao menos as gratificações serão.

Comment: @CaiodePaulaSilva, você conseguiu fazer os testes? Fiquei curioso para saber se a teoria está certa, e se deu tudo certo.

Comment: Sim, @Pedro Gaspar. Eu realizei alguns testes mas ainda não estou satisfeito com o resultado. Estive tentando desenvolver algo mais a partir de toda a assistência que você prestou porque acredito que o insucesso seja reflexo de algo bem pontual...  A tentativa de direcionar a saída da aplicação para um arquivo de texto executando-a a partir do cmd não funcionou. O arquivo permanece constantemente vazio. Seja preenchendo com argumentos válidos ou não. Quanto aos outros dois códigos fornecidos, ambos apresentam o mesmo resultado: funcionam de forma intermitente.

Comment: Verificando a saída via Console parece não haver muita diferença quando em relação ao MessageBox, aliás. Algumas vezes é possível obtê-la sem travar tudo e quando não, finalizo a aplicação pelo gerenciador de tarefas e _voilà_, a saída é visível. Como comentei, outro ponto que me intriga é a saída sempre vazia. Quando executo o programa normalmente via cmd eu sou capaz de acompanhar tudo perfeitamente visualmente. De qualquer forma. Muito obrigado. Sinto que estou muito mais próximo da solução.

Comment: @CaiodePaulaSilva, pesquisei um pouco mais e encontrei [essa pegunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7990851/8133067) no SOen, em que o autor teve um problema muito parecido com o seu e no final das contas era um bug no programa de terceiros. Você tem como entrar em contato com o fornecedor desse programa que você está usando? Eu editei a minha resposta para incluir essas informações e também uma possível solução para contornar esse problema, veja se agora finalmente vai!

Comment: @CaiodePaulaSilva, essas últimas informações que adicionei ajudaram em algo? Conseguiu entrar em contato com o fornecedor? Conseguiu ver o resultado do programa em tela, ao executar pelo seu aplicativo?

Comment: não consegui entrar em contato, infelizmente. E sim, consigo ver o resultado em tela, mas não é do meu desejo torna-la disponível. Minha intenção é realmente a de mantê-la em segundo plano.

Comment: @CaiodePaulaSilva, não sei se entendi, o que você quer dizer com "*mas não é do meu desejo torna-la disponível*" e com "*Minha intenção é realmente a de mantê-la em segundo plano*"? No primeiro exemplo da 'Edição 4' da resposta o prompt de comando não fica disponível e é fechado assim que o programa é finalizado.

Comment: Desculpe a demora. Explicando, o que planejo na verdade, é não tornar visível a resposta que estou adquirindo desta aplicação. Estou utilizando o MessageBox por hora, porque estou em testes, entretanto, minha intenção é manter tudo funcionando em segundo plano realmente. Eu não tenho a intenção de levantar qualquer janela ou qualquer informação ao usuário, essa é uma rotina para controle interno.

Comment: Eu encontrei [essa questão](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060019/command-prompt-output-being-read-as-empty-string), mas novamente não consigo reproduzir um resultado válido  com ela. Apesar de acreditar que ela seja de muita utilidade.

Comment: É, pode ser também, que o programa esteja mandando o output pro stream de erro! Em um dos links que postei na resposta (esse [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7990851/8133067), na Edição 4), o autor fez o redirecionamento no console dessa forma: `app.exe args > app_saida.txt 2>&1`, que redireciona inclusive o stream de erro também (ao bater o olho nesse comando na época eu não sabia do que se tratava, hehe, então fui [pesquisar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/818255/8133067)). Você pode usar esse comando no prompt para sanar a dúvida. Se continuar não saindo nada no arquivo texto, não é isso.

Comment: Mas, por que você não conseguiu reproduzir? O que houve? É mais ou menos o código que eu tinha passado na minha resposta também, a única diferença é que nessa resposta ele também está usando o evento `ErrorDataReceived`.

Comment: Mas o que você pretende fazer com o output dessa aplicação? Você iria analisar a saída (que iria para o console) para obter informações que seriam armazenadas internamente? E essa é a única forma de saída dessa aplicação?

Comment: você esteve certo desde a edição um. Muito obrigado pelo apoio e paciência. Por ignorância eu não notei que sua resposta era correta.O método para acessar as saídas é justamente esse. Tive esta epifania ao resgatar a mensagem de erro com total eficiência. Já quanto a outra saída, ela ainda tem retornado constantemente vazia, mas isso é um problema menor (e talvez realmente específico ao meu caso) e a pergunta já foi respondida. Você forneceu o método. De qualquer forma, seguirei tentando e edito a pergunta assim que for possível. Mais uma vez obrigado!

Comment: De nada Caio, que bom que deu certo, de alguma forma! Mas, dependendo do que for seria melhor você abrir uma nova pergunta, ao invés de editar essa pergunta que já está estabelecida e inclusive já tem respostas, para que a pergunta e as respostas não fiquem extensas demais, e para não misturar problemas distintos.

Answer (score 4):

Considerando que ele está em loop, já tentou usar peek? Exemplo:

```
processo.Start();

while (process.StandardOutput.Peek() > -1)
{
    MessageBox.Show(processo.StandardOutput.ReadLine());

}
```

Comment: Muito bem pensado, eu inda não havia experimentado isso. Entretanto, não funcionou.

Answer (score -1):

Mude isso:

```
processo.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = (Application.StartupPath + @"\Debug");
```

Por isso:

```
processo.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = (Application.StartupPath);
```

Pois só está duplicando a pasta no caminho.

Comment: Acredito que você não tenha compreendido o propósito deste trecho de código. O trecho que você destacou identifica em que diretório a aplicação está funcionando e diz que a partir deste ponto ele precisa procurar a pasta **Debug**. Esta funcionando perfeitamente neste sentido. Além disso, isso não me serve como resposta, talvez sim como um comentário. Aconselho repensar a resposta.

Comment: Ok, e sua aplicação está funcionando aonde? Em que pasta?